# All jQuery Deferred/Promise possible uses

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I've been playing with `$.Deferred` and `promise()`'s, and noticed that almost all jQuery methods have a `promise` method, so I'd like to know where else can the promise be used. So far, I'm aware it can be used in:

- Animation (`animate`, `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, `fadeTo`, `hide`, `show`, etc)
- AJAX (`$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get`, `$.getJSON`, etc)
- setTimeout functions (with `resolve` called manually inside one of the functions)
- Queue like implementions (execute commands in order, that can have other callbacks plugged-in on-the-fly)

Comment: Well, any asynchronous operation really. Just write a wrapper that does `.resolve()`/`.reject()` in the native callback. E.g. IndexedDB, FileSystem API, Web Workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the source code. It looks like the only one you missed is `$.ready.promise()`. This seems to treat the primary ready event of JQuery as a promise, so from the beginning you could write:

```
$.ready.promise()
 .then(function() { return $.ajax({ ... }); })
 .then(function(data)
     {
         // do something with data
     })
 .fail(function()
     {
         // handle errors
     });
```